# Trouble getting jQuery to talk with velocity

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, velocity

I have this input that is in a velocity file

```
<input name="$name_GradePoints" id="$name_GradePoints" value="$!value_GradePoints" type="text" size="5" maxlength="11"/>
```

and I am trying to get it to use a simple jQuery change event.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$('.target').change(function() {
  Something will happen.
});
</script>
```

.target will end up being the id on the input, I know that part.

That script is going to end up being a validator for the input.

I am just confused on what to pass in the change for jQuery

$name_GradePoints **OR** #$name_GradePoints **OR** #{$name_GradePoints}

Comment: Well, which kind of validation will you apply?

Comment: It's going to only allow decimal numbers.

I know I can end up using .allowDecimal.

Answer (score 0):

Use `#$name_GradePoints`:

```
$('#${name_GradePoints}').change(function() {
    Something will happen.
});
```

Or if you run into issues with jQuery and Velocity both wanting to use `$`, you can use jQuery's full name:

```
jQuery('#${name_GradePoints}').change(function() {
    Something will happen.
});
```

Comment: For some reason that doesn't work for me.

I tried this to debug it and it didn't work

jQuery('#$name_GradePoints').change(function() {
    alert("OK");
});

Comment: Try using Velocity's [formal reference notation](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/releases/velocity-1.4/user-guide.html#Formal%20Reference%20Notation).  I've updated the answer.

Comment: Also, view source on the rendered page and see if the Velocity variable is getting passed through as you expect.